# Difference between 一点也不and 一点都不

Tags: difference

Is there any rule in the phrase "一点也/都不..." when you should use 都 instead of 也 or can you simply use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native speaker, they seem no difference to me.
You can simply use them interchangeably when you want to say "xxx not at all".

e.g.

> 我一点都不记得。
> 我一点也不记得。
> I don't remember at all.

Comment: The only difference might be colloquial vs. literary. In Cantonese, 都 is more colloquial than 也. It may be different in Mandarin. For example,  我一啲印象都冇(colloquial Cantonese); 我一點印象也沒有(Standard Written Chinese/ Mandarin)